# How transform value pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data :

```
data = [
  (1, 'Shirt', 2),
  (1, 'Pants', 3),
  (2, 'Top', 2),
  (2, 'Shirt', 1),
  (2, 'T-Shirt', 4),
  (3, 'Shirt', 3),
  (3, 'T-Shirt', 2),
  (4, 'Top', 3),
  (4, 'Pants', 3),
  (4, 'T-Shirt', 3),
]
```

and I transform using `pandas` :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['unique_id', 'category_product', 'count'])
```

and matrix from `df` is :

```
    unique_id category_product  count
0          11            Shirt      2
1          11            Pants      3
2          24              Top      2
3          24            Shirt      1
4          24          T-Shirt      4
5          36            Shirt      3
6          36          T-Shirt      2
7          48              Top      3
8          48            Pants      3
9          48          T-Shirt      3
```

but I need change the `unique_id` start from 0, and increase in the order seen and result like :

```
   unique_id category_product  count
0          0            Shirt      2
1          0            Pants      3
2          1              Top      2
3          1            Shirt      1
4          1          T-Shirt      4
5          2            Shirt      3
6          2          T-Shirt      2
7          3              Top      3
8          3            Pants      3
9          3          T-Shirt      3
```

how can I do that?

Comment: sory my mistak, i have update my question @DSM

Comment: The example data array (although it does not match the result just below) seems like a simple `df['unique_id']-=1` would work, but I assume it's not that easy...?

Comment: sory @JoachimIsaksson, it's just -1 unique_id right ? but my target is change order from 0 increase order :(

Comment: Are they always sequential starting with 1 and you want them still sequential starting with 0? Since the data array you're showing won't result in the displayed data frame, it's a bit hard to figure out what you need.

Comment: `df` is dataframe, and i need change unique_id from minimum to 0 and increased ordered

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson i want to change to starting from 0 and sequential,,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be simpler ways, but here's one;

```
df.unique_id = (df.unique_id.diff() != 0).cumsum() - 1
```

Basically it just compares each row to the previous one, if the diff is != 0 it increases the output value by 1. The -1 at the end is to compensate for the leading NaN (where the first row has nothing to diff against)